# What is meaning of "Six" mentioned in Vaak 24?

Tags: kashmiri-shaivism, lal-ded

In Vaak 24, Lalleshvari Devi says:

> **You've got six and I have got six.**
> Now tell me, Blue-Throated One, what's difference?
> Or don't. I know. **You keep your six** on a leash
> and **my six have strung me along**

By reading this poem, it sounds like Lalleshvari Devi is talking about six characteristics of Shiva(Blue-Throated One) and six characteristics of her. While Shiva has control of his six characteristics, but she is being tied by her own six characteristics. This much I understood; but what are these six characteristics?

Comment: May be she is talking about our Shadripus or six enemies of a man. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arishadvargas

Comment: Yeah possible @Swift But what about six characteristics of Shiva?

Comment: It could be the five senses + mind = six

Comment: sad urmis  kama, krodha, moha, lobha, matsarya, and mada. These are desire, anger, delusion, greed, envy and sloth

Comment: @RamAbloh Please convert that to an answer.

Comment: Wait. How do you know "you," and the "Blue-Throated One," are the same person? She could just be invoking "Blue-Throated One," in order to understand the problem better. Is there context, where you can be sure who "you," is?

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa First of all She was Shaivite and was from Kashmiri Shaivism sect; so there is no doubt about it. Read this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43013/647

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto First of all, I have no idea what being Shaivite or not has to do with my question. This is a prayer to Śiva. Second of all can you link to the full Vaak. Third, my guess is that is related to the six wives/female extensions of the first human to describe the difference between a deity and a non-deity human. She is invoking Śiva by his poison drinker related name because these six are prosperous for the human deities but like poison to the non-deity humans who have no control over them. This entire verse is about the sadness that comes from not being in control.

Comment: * wives/female extensions in the Daśaratha, Vasudeva, Viṣṇuyaśas, avatars of the first human.

Comment: @Aupakarana you may want to compose an answer. Please add authentic sources when doing so.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Done (with proper good references! :-))

Answer (score 4):

First of all, we can only guess because, in the absence of a traditional commentary on a cryptic spiritual passage, that is what we can do at the most.

One guess is the Shad Ripus, as one comment under the question mentions. But my guess is it is talking about the six senses or the Shad Indriyas. Usually we talk about the 5 Indriyas (also known as the Buddhi Indriyas) -- eyes, ears, nose, skin and the tongue. Apart from this we have the Shasta Indriya (the sixth sense) which is the mind. If we count the Karma Indriyas as well ( genital, anus etc.) then there are 10+ the mind or 11 Indriyas in all.
Manu talks about these 11 (6, if we include only the Buddhi Indriyas) sense organs.

> Manu Smriti 2.88. A wise man should strive to restrain his organs
> which run wild among alluring sensual objects, like a charioteer his
> horses.
>
> 2.89. Those eleven organs which former sages have named, I will properly (and) precisely enumerate in due order,
>
> 2.90. (Viz.) the ear, the skin, the eyes, the tongue, and the nose as the fifth, the anus, the organ of generation, hands and feet, and the
> (organ of) speech, named as the tenth.
>
> 2.91. Five of them, the ear and the rest according to their order, they call organs of sense, and five of them, the anus and the rest,
> organs of action
>
> 2.92. Know that the internal organ (manas) is the eleventh, which by its quality belongs to both (sets); when that has been subdued, both
> those sets of five have been conquered.

If we are talking about enemies (Ripus), then we talk of killing them, where as, when we talk about the senses, then we talk about keeping them under control or restrain them. Upon seeing the passage, it seems to me it is talking about keeping the six senses (eyes, ears, tongue, skin, nose and the mind) under restraint, which lal-ded is unable to do at present.

"You keep your six on a leash" -- this in my view is clearly talking about lord Shiva keeping his six senses under his control because leash usually refers to a rope or belt used to control animals like dogs

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a correct interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

This Could be [Sad Urmis](http://balanceyogaindia.blogspot.com/2012/01/six-poisons-around-heart-also-referred.html) that brings down one.  kama, krodha, moha, lobha, matsarya, and mada. These are desire, anger, delusion, greed, envy and sloth.

But krishna says these 3 are primary reason for downfall not all of the above in BG Chp 16 verse 21:

> त्रिविधं नरकस्येदं द्वारं नाशनमात्मनः |
> कामः क्रोधस्तथा लोभस्तस्मादेतत्त्रयं त्यजेत् || २१ ||

> trividhaṃ narakasyedaṃ dvāraṃ nāśanamātmanaḥ
> kāmaḥ krodhastathā lobhastasmādetattrayaṃ tyajet 16.21

> त्रिविधं नरकस्येदं द्वारं - Bhagavan says that these are the three gateways to the hell. These are the threefold gateway to the hell. All the three doors lead to the hell.
> These are Kama (Lust) ->  Krodha results in anger (of not getting the desired) and loss of memory  -> Greed of Wealth(Not sharing wealth when in plenty)

Answer (score 1):

I think the most sensible and reasonable explanation of the "six" is five senses and the mind.

The phrase "मनःषष्ठानि इन्द्रियाणि" i.e. "the senses which have the mind as their sixth member" occurs explicitly in the Bhagavad Gita 15.7:

> ममैवांशो जीवलोके जीवभूतः सनातनः । **मनःषष्ठानीन्द्रियाणि** प्रकृतिस्थानि कर्षति ॥ 
> My own part enters the universe as the eternal living entity. It draws the senses with the mind as the sixth, and thus lives in the world.

Also, there are references to the senses being either "under control" or "out of control". For example, in Katha Upanishad 1.3.5-6:

> यस्त्वविज्ञानवान् भवत्ययुक्तेन मनसा सह । तस्येन्द्रियाण्यवश्यानि दुष्टाश्वा इव सारथेः ॥
> One who is unenlightened with an undisciplined mind, his senses are out of control, like the unruly horses disobeying their charioteer.
> यस्तु विज्ञानवान् भवति युक्तेन मनसा सह । तस्येन्द्रियाणि वश्यानि सदश्वा इव सारथेः ॥
> One who is enlightened with a disciplined mind, his senses are under control, like the obedient horses of their charioteer.

So the image of "horses" on "reins" or "leash" is present above.

Comment: Thank you! Upvoted :-)

Comment: Why not because sense organs themselves inert because it's just device getting used by atman

Comment: @RamAbloh I posted answer from the book itself. You may check it.

Answer (score 1):

From the book [I, Lalla: The Poems of Lal Ded, Page 164](https://archive.org/details/ilallathepoemsoflalded/page/n203/mode/2up) Author Ranjit Hoskote gives explanation on this vaak 24:

> Shiva came to possess this anatomical attribute because he swallowed a deadly poison, the haldhale, which was thrown up when the gods and demons joined to churn the Ocean of Milk to draw up the nectar of immortality, the amrita. In saving the world from the toxicity of halähala, Shiva placed himself at risk: forever after, he held the poison in his throat, which turned blue, a marked contrast against his pale, ash-smeared body. A symbol of Shiva's gesture as saviour, the blue throat is also a token of his ability to control his faculties, command circumstances and withstand all negativity.
> ....
> Here, extending George Grierson's speculations (1920, 35), I would suggest that **Shiva's 'six' are the attributes of the Supreme Deity, namely eternity, omniscience. omnipotence, absolute tranquillity, absolute self-sufficiency and the ability to reside beyond form while manifesting Itself at will. Lalla's 'six', meanwhile, may well signify the weaknesses of the unreconstructed human self, namely lust, anger, greed, arrogance, delusion and envy, some of which appear elsewhere in the LD corpus.**