# Buddhi and its details

Tags: translation, buddhi

Many [verses](https://asitis.com/3/42.html) in scriptures gives the following ordering w.r.t to a human being

> 1. Organs
> 2. Manas
> 3. **Buddhi**
> 4. Soul

and some people say that there exists another one

> 5. Atman

My doubt is about Buddhi part only and the questions are

1. Is there any word in English that correctly explain the meaning of Buddhi in this context? Is it knowledge or intelligence or wisdom or any other?
2. Is there any further classification of Buddhi? For example [organs can be further classified](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43132/661) in to two types and further in to five types of each class.

Comment: did u find its details?

Comment: @Harsh Not yet!